# Set color of SKShapeNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I have an SKShapeNode, defined by a circleWithRadius. When I try to modify the color of node with `node.fillColor`, gets filled the entire area around the circle, not just the area defined by circle path. My question is: how can I fill just the inner area of node?

**Edit**

Here is my code:

```
    let bigCirle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: baseControlerRadius)
    bigCirle.position = CGPointMake(self.view!.frame.size.width * 0.85, (self.view?.frame.size.height)! * 0.15)
    bigCirle.fillColor = SKColor.blueColor()
    bigCirle.name = bigCircleControlerSKNodeName
    self.addChild(bigCirle)
```

Comment: You mean the entire node's frame is filled instead of just the inside area of the circle?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to say

Comment: Setting the `fillColor` property of a shape node should only fill in the circle. I suggest you post the code that creates the shape.

Comment: Here's the doc for SKShapeNode. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKShapeNode_Ref/ @0x141E is right that `fillColor` should work. Perhaps if you're not seeing what you want, you could explicitly define `clearColor` for `strokeColor`

Comment: Edited my post with code

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted. You should see a blue circle with a thin white outline. Are you running the latest Xcode?

Comment: I'm running Xcode 7 beta

Comment: Did you check the baseControllerRadius size because maybe the reason could be your skshape is too big to fit in the self view.

Comment: Circle fits in view just fine. I'm sure this is just a bug from Xcode, unfortunately  it's not the first one.

Comment: I have this same problem.  Did you ever get a solution?

Comment: Same problem here. It's weird because on iPad device it works fine. However on iPhone simulator the whole node is really colored, instead just the inner circle.